# Internet availability checking automatically in app after some period of time interval in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have developed an ios app which stores admission form data in sqlite when there is no internet connection in objective c .consider a case like , after some time  internet comes and data in sqlite should be fetched and updated automatically in server through api call without killing or close the app. is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and add a delegate to it - it will notify you when the reachability state changes. It's better to get notified on a change than having to ping it every few seconds.

There are examples on how to use it on their page, so I'm not going to repeat it here.